# Include folder in referenced project as MauiAssets

Tags: msbuild, maui

## Goal

I have a MAUI project, which references a (non-MAUI) "core" library project.
The core project is where a user of this framework will (mostly) work in.
I want to include files from the core project in the MAUI app.

## Research

For other platform projects - e.g. linux desktop - this is easy, because dotnet can simply copy the files from the core project. This even works recursively for projects which the core project references.
In MAUI, however, I understand that for cross-compatibility reasons, those files need to have their build action be `MauiAsset`. Which can be done manually, or by putting them under the folder `Resources\Raw`, which does this for all files automatically.

I see that the MAUI project dutifully copies files from the core project's OutDir to its own. I tried to copy things from there to `$(ProjectDir)\Resources\Raw` via msbuild target. However, I can not find the right build target to hook into, and I suspect that those files are copied too late in the process (= after MAUI processes `Resources\Raw`).

I have also noticed that MAUI builds take quite long compared to other platforms, so I do not want to make the core project a MAUI library.

## Question

How can I include files from such a "core" project into a MAUI project, in a way that is as easy as possible for the framework user working on that core project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up solving this via more elaborate msbuild functionality:

In the core project

- Use a `Target` with `BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"`
- Gather all assets I want to include into an `<ItemGroup>`
- Save them in a file via the `WriteLinesToFile` task

In the referencing project

- Have another `Target` on `BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"`.
- Find the files created above - I did this by using a file extension so specific that it's unlikely it would collide with files created by something else (I think I used "*.assets.g.txt")
- Use the `ReadLinesFromFile` task to read the lines back into an `<ItemGroup>`. This could be `<MauiAsset>` directly.